# Why I am getting 2 different outputs for same function(substr) in a string?

Tags: c++, string, output, substring, substr

I wrote a code to find the substring from of a string from after "I have a " which is specifically nine characters. It gives the correct output on the first input but misses the first character on the second.
Can anyone please tell me why ??

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        string s1;
        getline(cin,s1);
        
        string s2;
        getline(cin,s2);
        
        int n1=s1.length();
        int n2=s2.length();
        
        string itema,itemb;
        itema=s1.substr(9,n1);
        cout<<itema<<endl;
        itemb=s2.substr(9,n2);
        cout<<itemb<<endl;
        cout<<"Uh! "<<itemb<<"-"<<itema<<"!"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR08C.png)

Comment: `cin.ignore()` eats the first character of the first line of input, the second time through the loop.

Comment: Couple of pointers here: prefer `using` to `#define`, you don't need the c headers ending with .h, the `using namespace std;` is best avoided, and so is `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Avoid aliases for built in types such as `#define ll long long int`, they introduce confusion.

Comment: Mixing `getline` and `>>` can be tricky.  Also, your code doesn't check for input failure, so if/when input failure occurs it might do unexpected things.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058)